# Translation of Revelations 21:24

Tags: revelation, greek

While doing a word study on sōzō, I noticed that most translations of Revelation 21:24, do not include the word “saved”

> (ASV) **And the nations shall walk amidst the light*

Only (13) translations use the word “saved”

> (KJV) *And the nations of them which are saved shall walk in the light*

Is there a reason for this discrepancy? Do the oldest versions of scripture have “saved” or “sōzō” ?

Answer (score 2):

Before the King James translation first came out in 1611, the Greek Text of Stephanus (Stephens) (1550) was in vogue. This uses manuscripts that have the *'sozo'* word in it for 'saved' in the text in question - "And the nations of the saved in its light shall walk" goes the literal Greek translation.

Just to mention by the way, that verse 26 is a bit similar in parts to that verse 24, but no translation has σωζομένων (saved) in it, so not even Stephens in *The Englishman's Greek New Testament* speaks of saved nations in verse 26, though he does in verse 24.

From 1862 till his final edition of the Bible in 1898, Robert Young rendered the text in question as "and the nations of the saved in its light shall walk" - *Young's Literal Translation of the Bible*.

So, there are three translations that use *'sozo'* (saved) in that verse 24. And that's only what I came across after a brief look through translations I have here at home. I will not dwell further on this, though there may be other such translations, because the bottom line is this:

The manuscripts used as the basis for saying "the nations of the saved" have *'sozo'* in them. The three translations I have mentioned have ***not*** "added a phrase" about those "who are saved". It's there in the *Textus Receptus*.

The manuscripts used as the basis for most modern translations do not have that phrase because it's not in their preferred manuscripts. Therefore the question will be answered according to the manuscript preferences of the answerers. Those who think the *Textus Receptus* is more reliable at that point will say it is correct to speak of saved nations in verse 24.

However, one point *does* need mentioning, as it may account for the charge that the King James version has added that phrase. I have the Greek Interlinear of Alfred Marshall, which uses the Nestle Greek text. Dr. Marshall gives his literal English of that text. The frontispiece says "Including the text of the Authorised Version". But although the Greek Nestle text does not have σωζομένων in verse 24, and so neither does Dr. Marshall, the English translation *does* as it follows the King James text. **That is a reason for this discrepancy.**

This goes to illustrate that the Nestle Greek text is not always faithful to the manuscripts used in the King James Translation. For a sound basis for that, it might be better to stick to *"The Englishman's Greek New Testament"* of Stephens, with its readings of Editions of Elzevir (1624), Griesbach, Lachmann, Tishendorf, Tregelles, Alford and Wordsworth.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Anne. Like I have said, my depth of knowledge on all these MMS’s is very shallow, but as I research answers like yours and @Dottard…..I feel my feet getting wet!
In defense of Dottard (not that he needs my help), I feel his answer was saying that the TR added “saved” (not the KJV). Yes, my question quoted the KJV, but that was just one of 13 translations that I found on BibleGateway.

Comment: So, I agree with you Anne, that it does not appear that the KJV “added” saved, they just used the TR as their base manuscript. 
What I’m learning is that the debate revolves around the minimal number of transcripts that Erasmus used in order to create the TR. But the counter to that concern is the wealth of knowledge that Erasmus had, as well as other scholars before him. Likely an unresolvable debate….but interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The text of Rev 21:24 is disputed; there are (excepting some minor differences) essentially two different texts:

1. Those of NA28, UBS5, W&H, Byzantine text, Majority text, SBL, Souter, NIVGNT, THGNT, Orthodox Text, F35, etc has this text:

> καὶ περιπατήσουσιν τὰ ἔθνη διὰ τοῦ φωτὸς αὐτῆς, καὶ οἱ βασιλεῖς τῆς
> γῆς φέρουσιν τὴν δόξαν αὐτῶν εἰς αὐτήν· = And the nations will walk by
> its light, and the kings of the earth bring their glory into it.

2. The Textus Receptus (TR) has this text:

> καὶ τὰ ἔθνη τῶν **σωζομένων** ἐν τῷ φωτί αὐτῆς περιπατήσουσι· καὶ οἱ
> βασιλεῖς τῆς γῆς φέρουσι τὴν δόξαν καὶ τὴν τιμὴν αὐτῶν εἰς αὐτήν· =
> And the nations of those who **are saved** shall walk in its light, and
> the kings of the earth bring their glory and honor into it.

Note that, almost alone, the Textus Receptus adds a phrase, "who are saved".  This phrase has almost no support among either the early of late MSS.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have no in-depth understanding of any of these texts. Chose to do a quick review of the Textus Receptus , simply because it was listed by itself.
Under Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textus_Receptus#:~:text=Typographical%20errors%2C%20attributed%20to%20the,Vulgate%20to%20finish%20his%20edition
I clicked on an article under "External Links" that caught my attention. http://wayoflife.org/fbns/isthereceived.htm

Comment: If you have the time to read it, I would be interested in your brief thoughts (Ex: do you think the defense was overly biased? Do you think the content/source is reliable…..or just fake news)

Comment: @matt - I have read this before.  It clearly shows the short-comings of the TR.